# Random Hardware Anomalies after accidental reverse polarity

Tags: windows, mac, freeze, power

Good afternoon everyone,
I have a bit of a weird question for you. About a month ago, I purchased a used Mac Pro 1,1 (2006). I proceeded to slap a GTX 1050ti in it, install windows and everything is running fine (obviously no mac OS as it's too old without hacks to get above lion).

Fast forward to last Saturday. I moved in with a friend pending an apartment change, set up my computer in his basement, and noticed that when the mac changed over to BIOS emulation, it would display the GTX 1050 info, then flash a bright white screen before booting windows. I thought it was no big deal, after all, windows booted fine.

Since then, I've been having progressively worse issues. It started with that bright white screen, then I noticed that the metal ring around my mechanical keyboard seemed to be shocking me when I got the mouse close enough for my thumb to touch it. Maybe the keyboard is defective, tho it's only about 3 weeks old...

Then the booting problems started. It started to freeze during the windows boot process (the little dot circle would stop in place, then the PC would restart). Now I'm starting to wonder if it's a hardware issue. I swapped the original ram sticks back into the machine, thinking maybe it didn't like the 2x8gb kit i added after "upgrading" the SMC/EFI to think it was a Mac Pro 2,1. Still had to fight it to boot.

When it did boot properly (with the 2x8gb kit re-added), I noticed that the bottom row of my keyboard (keys shift all the way right to the numpad enter key) was very dimly lit in comparison to the rest of the keys. On top of this, anything plugged into the rear USB ports on the mac would randomly disconnect every ~20 minutes or so.

Now i'm starting to think it's a ground issue. The outlet happens to be about 15ft across the room, so it's running on a heavy-duty extension cord (15amps max) over to a surge protector. I shut the mac down today, and inspected the extension cord, to which I discovered that my friend had removed the ground pin, and inserted the male end of the extension cord such that its polarity was reversed. [Here's a picture of the cord, for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRO6c.jpg) This makes me think my suspicion of ground issues was right, plus there's the whole "reverse polarity" thing...

I went to my local hardware store and bought a replacement extension cord with the proper ground pin, brought it home, made sure that the outlet was actually grounded, then swapped the cords.

Unfortunately, this has not resolved ANY of the issues with my PC (I know it's a mac, but I'm using it as a PC). The white screen still persists, it takes me about 6/10 tries to get the PC to boot (including several visits to  windows 10's automatic repair), that row of lights on my keyboard is still extremely dim in comparison to the other keys, I still feel a tingle from the metal rim around it and as I'm typing this, the USB ports in the rear just reset again.

As for the windows automatic repair, it always errors, ending with the following at the bottom of the StrTrail.txt file

```
Root cause found: 
---------------------------
Boot critical file h:\boot\resources\custom\bootres.dll is corrupt.

Repair action: File repair
Result: Failed. Error code =  0x2
Time taken = 3593 ms
```

My question is, could the reverse polarity/lack of ground caused these issues? I never noticed them before I plugged the pc in at my friend's house which makes me think there might be at least SOME damage done to it.

*edit* I did /sfc scannnow and it returned

> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

I also ran

> chkdsk c: /f /r

however I haven't restarted the PC yet as I'm a little weary of it not booting (again).

Also, here's a pic of the keyboard
[MechanicalKeyboardPic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVDlx.jpg)

Comment: I assume you are no longer getting shocks?

Comment: I don't appear to be, however I haven't intentionally tested it as of yet

Comment: I think that there is a short somewhere; otherwise, you should not be getting any high voltage through the keyboard. The AC power will have to go through a power supply and there should be only low voltage DC coming out.

Comment: What country is this in?  In US and EU the plug can’t be plugged into a power socket incorrectly

Comment: USA, and he removed the ground pin _totally_ which allowed him to plug it in upside down not realizing it [Picture of Male end of Extension Cord](https://i.imgur.com/JtJgLN3.jpg)

Comment: @BenH do you have a GFCI outlet in the bathroom or kitchen? It won't hurt to plug your MacPro in the 3 prong GFCI outlet to see if it triggers a ground fault.

Comment: Apologies on such a late reply, I finally rebooted my PC to do the chkdsk, it stayed at 14% for what seemed like _forever_, then jumped to 100%, rebooted, and froze, causing my PC to stay in a chkdsk loop forever (as it kept restarting the test, "compeleting" it, then freezing and restarting the test).

I finally gave up and ran chkdsk from the advanced startup menu, doing chkdsk /f first, then chkdsk /r. 

[/f results](https://i.imgur.com/Ry18NJW.jpg)
[/r results part 1](https://i.imgur.com/uGrSoZ4.jpg)
[/r results part 2](https://i.imgur.com/TK0euWq.jpg)

Comment: Pressed enter too early, took to long to try and add the stuff i forgot. Unfortunately, I don't have a GFCI outlet that I can see, however there don't appear to be _any_ outlets in the bathroom. Also, an update on the USB disconnections, it appears to be _just the mouse_ disconnecting, as I use a USB Keyboard and headset which do not disconnect when the mouse does.

Comment: Yet another update; The random USB disconnects were solely the mouse I was using at the time, and since switching to a spare mouse, they seem to have stopped. My thumb does still feel like it's being shocked when I touch the keyboard, however it's not as sharp of a feeling, more like a "tingling" now. And the computer still has the boot issues, to which I'm wondering might be a corrupted windows install. Might try re-installing after work.